# VRTK_ControllerEvents returning null

Tags: unity-game-engine, vrtk

I am trying to make a gun in Unity with SteamVR and VRTK but I can't figure out how to properly get controller input. When I use the SteamVR Tracked Controller script I get an IsMatrixValid error and it messes up my HMD. I am currently trying to use VRTK controller events method but it keeps returning as a null even though I followed the video correctly.

[Screenshot of script location in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ivd7m.jpg)

Video in question: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=escwjnHFce0
(14:17)

Script in question:

```c#
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using EZEffects;
using VRTK;


public class GunBehavior : MonoBehaviour {

public VRTK_ControllerEvents controllerEvents;

private SteamVR_TrackedObject trackedObj;


public EffectTracer TracerEffect;
public Transform muzzleTransform;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    Debug.Log(controllerEvents);
    if (controllerEvents)
    {
        Debug.Log("Hue22");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("work");
    }
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    if (controllerEvents.triggerPressed)
    {
        ShootWeapon();
    }
}

void TriggerPressed(object sender, VRTK.ControllerInteractionEventArgs e)
{
    ShootWeapon();
}

void ShootWeapon()
{
    RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
    Ray ray = new Ray(muzzleTransform.position, muzzleTransform.forward);

    TracerEffect.ShowTracerEffect(muzzleTransform.position, muzzleTransform.forward, 250f);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 5000f))
    {
        Debug.Log("Hueheuhue");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Where is "returning null" happening?

Answer (score 0):

Delete these 3 lines of code from your scrip and it should work

```
void TriggerPressed(object sender, VRTK.ControllerInteractionEventArgs e)
{
    ShootWeapon();
}
```